# Hash Map Sorting in java8

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have following HashMap

```
"1":
   {
    "profilePic":null,
    "roleNo" : "12"
   },
 "2": 
   {
    "profilePic":null,
    "roleNo" : "1"
   }
```

I want the output as below

```
   "2":
   {
    "profilePic":null,
    "roleNo" : "1"
   },
 "1": 
   {
    "profilePic":null,
    "roleNo" : "12"
   }
```

I have tried the below code but didn't get the output as expected

```
LinkedHashMap<Long, Person> newPerson = attendanceMap
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(new AttendanceListComparator()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

My attendancelistcomparator is as below

```
@Override
public int compare(Person s1, Person s2) {
    return sortingOrder*s1.getRoleno().compareTo(s2.getRoleno());
}
```

Please suggest me something to get the sorted data

Comment: You might want to use `TreeMap`

Comment: What is the sortingOrder you are passing?? What is the output with that value??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi the sortingOrder is 1

Comment: Try using s2.getRoleno().compareTo(s1.getRoleno())

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I have tried but didn't get the output :-(

Comment: @ankit does my answer solve your problem? If not, could you ask for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will sort your `HashMap` entries and store it in a list:

```
List<Map.Entry<Long, Player>> sorted = mapp.entrySet().stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getKey))
     .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sort by value for the map. While sorting by value use 'Roleno' of the Person object. If you want to sort in ascending order of use

```
o1.getRoleno().compareTo(o2.getRoleno())
```

otherwise if you want to sort in descending order use

```
o2.getRoleno().compareTo(o1.getRoleno())
```

A sample code could be as follows:

```
private static Map<Long, Person> sortByValueMap(Map<Long, Person> unsortMap) {

    List<Map.Entry<Long, Person>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Long, Person>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Long, Person>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Long, Person> o1, Map.Entry<Long, Person> o2) {
            return (o2.getRoleno()).compareTo(o1.getRoleno());
        }
    });


    Map<Long, Person> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Person>();
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Person> entry : list) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedMap;
}
```

Hope this helps. if you have any further queries please write it in comment.